# Animation offset

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a divider that slides upwards into view using animations courtesy of [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), specifically using the fadeInUp animation.

However, the divider doesn't really 'slide' into view as much as it just fades in. You can see the visualization of this in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq2qpgyp/).

Is there any way I can offset the divider animation, so that it starts from a lower point and actually slides up, as opposed to simply fading in in a specific spot?

HTML:

```
<h1 class="animated fadeInUp">Text text text</h1>
<div class="divider animated fadeInUp"></div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.divider {
  background-color: #808082;
  height: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
     transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
   animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way is to use `:pseudo` element `:after` for adding divider

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/tq2qpgyp/4/

```
h1:after {
    content:'';
    background-color: #808082;
    height: 2px;
    width: 80px;
    display:block;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h1:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #808082;
  height: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="animated fadeInUp">Text text text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way: add a border to the divider

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tq2qpgyp/2/)**

```
.divider {
  background-color: #808082;
  height: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  border-top: 20px solid white; /* <--- added */
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.divider {
  background-color: #808082;
  height: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  border-top: 20px solid white;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="animated fadeInUp">Text text text</h1>
<div class="divider animated fadeInUp"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:after` property of css like this..

You can write anything in `content:'';`

This is the [special character library](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/)

```css
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

h1:after{
    content:'\2014\2014\2014';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-25px;
    left:50px;
    word-spacing: 30px;
    
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
          animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="animated fadeInUp">Text text text</h1>
```